# stopping the expansion of the safari window after opening a new tab

Tags: macos, safari, window-manager, tabs

When opening a new tab in safari while not browsing in full-screen mode, the safari window expands, in order to preserve the content of the webpage shown. I think this is quite annoying, is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: I understand that the window grows in height, to welcome the bar of tabs.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, but it would be nice if I could turn it off.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of an elegant solution, but choosing to always show the tab bar will never have to increase the size of the window, since it would always be there

Comment: That's indeed a solution, but not what I was looking for...